# Background images have small height

Tags: html, css

I just want two `<a/>` tags with background images to be in the center side by side and have full image size.
I know that if I add

```
  height: 68px;
  width: 200px;
```

this would help, but I'd like to do  regardless of images size.

Here's an example:

```css
.logos {
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo:first-child {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/173x68');
}

.logo:last-child {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x68');
}

.visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* 1 */
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logos">
  <a href="#" class="logo">
    <span class='visuallyhidden'>1st link</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="logo">
    <span class='visuallyhidden'>2nd link</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here's  what I want it to look like:
[image]

Comment: @Tomm Ok I remove the part of question for mobile

Comment: @Bhargav question is more about image size

Comment: Just set the height and don't set any width value

Comment: must you use the background image instead of inline image?

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv If you are only using background image, you need to atleast declare a minimum height for the image to display, but if you are using an inline image, no matter what's the width and size if can't be resize and position proportionally.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-size: 68px 200px;

Comment: What If 'll change image size to 300px 300px - would it still work?  - I asked about universal solution